# npm semantic-release - specify version

Tags: semantic-release

I am using npm semantic-release in my project (https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-release).  While I understand that the idea is not to tinker with the calculated version, I would like to create a specific version as a one off.  Does anyone know if and how this is possible?

For example let's say I'm on version `1.0.1`, I'd like to create version `1.0.2-desc.1`.  After this is released I'd like to continue with `1.0.3`/`1.1.0`/`2.0.0` or whatever is next.

Comment: Sure you can: https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/HEAD/docs/recipes/pre-releases.md#publishing-pre-releases

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @msanford I saw this, it's kind of what.  But I really want it without the additional branches and with the flexibility to specify any version name. In the end bypassing semantic-release, as a one-off, seems to be my best option.

Answer (score 0):

After reflection, I think it's not possible. I can make a specific one-off release by bypassing semantic-release entirely and then re-instating it afterwards.  It's just a shame there wasn't a simple way to do this without changing a whole lot, but perhaps the point is to dissuade you from doing it unless absolutely necessary.